# How to add a dynamic prefix in sequence in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to implement a sequence using a dynamic prefix, but I can't.
I can't pass a varible since *.py to my *.xml
I try using "context" and "domain" but I recieve the following error message:
"AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 4"

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

   <record id="seq_obra" model="ir.sequence">
      <field name="name">Secuencia Obra</field>
      <field name="code">secuencia.obra</field>
      <field name="prefix">%(prefijo)</field>  <-- this is the variable that i want to read from my .py
      <field name="padding">3</field>
   </record>
```

My py code is:

```
class Poscontrata(models.Model):
   _name = 'poscontrata'
   name = fields.Char(string='Descripcion', required=True)
   sigla = fields.Char(required=True)
   area_id = fields.Many2many('area', string='Area')
   active = fields.Boolean(default=True)

   @api.model
   def create (self,values):
      area_cod =  values['area_id'][0][2]
      ctd_area_dsc = len(area_cod)

      for x in range(0, ctd_area_dsc):
      prefijo = '-' + values['sigla'] + '-' + self.env['area'].search([('id', '=', area_cod[x])], limit=1).sigla + '-'   
      function_call_sequence_and_send_variable('secuencia.obra','prefijo') <-- this is the function that i need

      return super (Poscontrata,self).create(values)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try using browse(id) instead of search(id=id, limit =1)?

Comment: What you want to do ? If you want to set dynamic sequence than it's already in setting.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in the python function, only take the next number of my sequence and then construct my new name.

Python function in .py:

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        correlativo_en_db = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('ruta.sequence')
        numero_correlativo = re.findall("\d+", correlativo_en_db)[0]
        fecha_entrega = vals['fecha']
        correlativo = fecha_entrega + '/' + numero_correlativo
        vals['name'] = correlativo
        result = super(Ruta, self).create(vals)
```

My sequnence record (XML):

```
    <record id="seq_ruta" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Ruta</field>
        <field name="code">ruta.sequence</field>
        <field name="prefix">X</field>
        <field name="padding">2</field>
        <field name="use_date_range">True</field>
        <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

name = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('your_sequence_code')